# Python: compare between variable to dictionary key in list

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to compare between variable to dictionary key in list,
even if one is up-case and the other low-case so   `AbC == aBC`.

this is part of my code which not working with unknown reason:

```
def information_on_albums(albums_names,user_information):
# albums names is list which every index is dictionary,^^string
    user_information = user_information.upper()
    for album in albums_names:
        if album.key().upper() == user_information:
           print album.value()`
```

Comment: just to make your question more clear can you provide some albums_names and user_information example?

Comment: plus what is exactly your question?

Comment: this names relevant for my code, and this part not working

Comment: honestly i have an hard time understanding your question. I put a solution guessing what you wanted. is this correct?

Comment: So, did any of our solution helped? if yes please vote and close the question!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you want to do is access the dictionary by his key in a non case sensitive manner. Here how you could do so:

```
def information_on_albums(albums_names,user_information):
# albums names is list which every index is dictionary,^^string
    user_information = user_information.upper()
    for album in albums_names:
        if album.upper() == user_information:
           return albums_names[album]

#test
albums_names = {"name1":"aaa","name2":"bbb","name3":"ccc"}
user_information = "NAME2"
print information_on_albums(albums_names,user_information)
```

this piece of code prints "bbb" even passing "NAME2" capitalized.

Be careful however that if you have a dicytionary as follow:

```
albums_names = {"name1":"aaa","name2":"bbb","NAME2":"ccc"}
```

"bbb" will be returned and not "ccc"

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
def information_on_albums(albums_names,user_information):
# albums names is list which every index is dictionary,^^string
    for albums in albums_names:
        print [ v for k, v in albums.items() if k.upper() == user_information.upper() ]

albums_names = [{"name1":"aaa","name2":"bbb","name3":"ccc"}]
user_information = "NAME2"
information_on_albums(albums_names,user_information)
```

Output:

```
['bbb']
```